# How to send doc file to database in asp.net

Tags: .net, asp.net, file-upload

I want to send `(INSERT)` a doc file, e.g resume into a table of my database. What is the code required to perform this in `asp.net 3.5`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the posted file into a Byte Stream.

```
byte[] myByte = new byte[fupUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength];
Stream imgStream = fupUpload.PostedFile.InputStream;
imgStream.Read(myByte, 0, fupUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength);
```

Then save the `myByte` stream into the DB using the ADO.NET Model, that you are using in your application.